# Query ID for name, if not found insert name and return ID

Tags: sql, postgresql

I really struggle to find a efficient way in one postgresql script to ask for the id primary key where the name is X but if not found insert name X and returning id primary key. Im doing it from Python using psycopg2.

I have for simplicity a two col table. A primary key and a character name.

The code below works if it is found and returns me the ID.

```
SELECT part_id FROM parts WHERE part_name='testing2'
```

The code below works if it is not found and returns me the new ID

```
INSERT INTO parts(part_name)
SELECT 'testing2'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM parts WHERE part_name='testing2')
RETURNING part_id
```

I would like to have one call where the server checks everything instead of first asking for the key then checking if it returns anything then sending a new command where I insert the new name and extract the ID for the name.

I simple could not get any of kind of similar questions online to work. Somebody using IFs but could not get anything to work.

Thanks in advance

F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres you can use CTEs, which can include `INSERT`:

```
WITH p AS (
      SELECT part_id
      FROM parts
      WHERE part_name = 'testing2'
     ),
     i AS (
      INSERT INTO parts (part_name)
          SELECT 'testing2'
          WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM p)
          RETURNING part_id
     )
SELECT p.part_id FROM p
UNION ALL
SELECT i.part_id FROM i;
```

Comment: Wow that is a  super usefull way of doing stuff in general! Thank you so much its also gonna help me in the future for lots of problems

Comment: what if i try to insert a  list ? does it become a lot more complicated then? so i ask for mulitple part ids. then it inserts multiple if they are missing

Comment: @TheFrederik . . . You can insert multiple columns using the same idea.  However, you should ask a new question if it is not clear on how to extend this logic.